# Function for quantifying lists: syntax and type error (Isabelle)

Tags: function, recursion, isabelle

I'm currently working through the 'Quantifying Lists' exercise from http://isabelle.in.tum.de/exercises/. It asks to 'Define a universal and an existential quantifier on lists using primitive recursion.  Expression @{term "alls P xs"} should
be true iff @{term "P x"} holds for every element @{term x} of
@{term xs}...'

This attempt looks believable to me:

```
primrec alls :: "('a ⇒ bool) ⇒ 'a list ⇒ bool" where
"alls P x # [] = (if P x then True else False)"
| "alls P x # xs = (if P x then alls P xs else False)"
```

I'm trying to write what I would express in mathematical notation as:

alls(P,[x]) = { if Px then true otherwise false

and

alls(P, [x, ...]) = { if Px then alls(P,[...]) otherwise false.

However, Isabelle says that there is a 'type error in unification' and shows that `x` is being assumed to have type `'a list`. I feel that I have not expressed the syntax rightly, but I am not sure how it ought to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to treat `x # foo` as a single operand it should be enclosed in parentheses: `(x # foo)`.

However this is not the end of the story: after applying the fix above you'll get an error `Nonprimitive pattern in left-hand side at "alls P [x]" ...` The offending pattern is `x # []` that matches a single-element list.

Lists are defined using two constructors `Nil` and `Cons` and `primrec` does not allow for non-primitive constructors, including single-element lists (that look like `Cons x Nil`). One can replace `primrec` with `fun` to avoid this error, but the issue is deeper if you want to define a total function, i.e. to handle empty lists as well.

To address this the function should have patterns for both primitive constructors `Nil` and `Cons`:

```
primrec alls :: "('a ⇒ bool) ⇒ 'a list ⇒ bool" where
  "alls P [] = ..."
| "alls P (x # xs) = (if P x then alls P xs else False)"
```

The part `...` is missing intentionally so that you can fill it with an appropriate value.

Comment: Thanks! I've worked it out now (`True` in the `...`) I'll know how to respond when I get the error message `Nonprimitive pattern` in future.

Comment: Note that `P x ∧ alls P xs` is better than `if P x then alls P xs else False`, since it avoids unnecessary case splitting and Isabelle's automation is very good at reasoning about conjunctions.